# Test method returning N days before today

Tags: java, junit

I'm a bit confused, I have a method which returns date N day before today, However I do not now how to test it:

```
public String getBeforeDay(int noDays){

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-noDays);

    DateFormat dateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = calendar.getTime();

    return dateFormat.format(date);
}

@Test
public void testGetBeforeDay(){
    assertEquals("2014-04-02", dateService.getBeforeDay(10));
}
```

and as string in the assertEquals is hardcoded, tommorow test will not pass. What is a good practise to solve such test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is a good practise to solve such test?

The problem is that you're depending on something ephemeral: the current date/time.

The fix I prefer for this is to introduce the idea of a `Clock` as a dependency (to be handled as with any other dependency) which can tell you the current time. For example:

```
public interface Clock {
    Date now();
}
```

You can then have one implementation which uses the system clock, and a fake to be used for testing. In your `getBeforeDay` method, you'd initialize the `Calendar` using:

```
calendar.setTime(clock.now());
```

I've used this approach very successfully in various projects, and the `java.time` package in Java 8 comes with it baked in. (If you can possibly use `java.time` instead of `java.util.*`, do so!)